# Cluster analysis: Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Opossum","Hairy tail mole", "Common mole", "Star nose mole"),I = c(5,3,3,3),i = c(4,3,2,3),C = c(1,1,1,1),c = c(1,1,0,1),P = c(3,4,3,4),p = c(3,4,3,4),M = c(4,3,3,3),m = c(4,3,3,3))
```

I am trying to implement cluster analysis. While scaling the dataset using

`data <- scale(data)`
But I am getting the error: Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric.
What is the reason?

Comment: Likely, `scale()` is trying to scale the name variable as well.  How about `scale(data[,-1])`

Answer (score 1):

Your error says that your data should be `numeric`. Your first column is a character which means you do not need to select that column. As @DaveArmstrong suggested in the comments, you can do this using the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Opossum","Hairy tail mole", "Common mole", "Star nose mole"),I = c(5,3,3,3),i = c(4,3,2,3),C = c(1,1,1,1),c = c(1,1,0,1),P = c(3,4,3,4),p = c(3,4,3,4),M = c(4,3,3,3),m = c(4,3,3,3))

data <- scale(df[,-1])
data
```

Output:

```
       I         i   C    c          P          p    M    m
[1,]  1.5  1.224745 NaN  0.5 -0.8660254 -0.8660254  1.5  1.5
[2,] -0.5  0.000000 NaN  0.5  0.8660254  0.8660254 -0.5 -0.5
[3,] -0.5 -1.224745 NaN -1.5 -0.8660254 -0.8660254 -0.5 -0.5
[4,] -0.5  0.000000 NaN  0.5  0.8660254  0.8660254 -0.5 -0.5
attr(,"scaled:center")
   I    i    C    c    P    p    M    m 
3.50 3.00 1.00 0.75 3.50 3.50 3.25 3.25 
attr(,"scaled:scale")
        I         i         C         c         P         p         M         m 
1.0000000 0.8164966 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.5773503 0.5773503 0.5000000 0.5000000
```